# Google dataflow, DATA_LOSS Exception

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am getting below DATA_LOSS exception from google data flow. I have 10-15 Json files(size around 2-3 MB per file). I am parsing the files using jackson2, couple of transformation using ParDo() and in the end doing group by to remove the duplicate items. Can you please help if i am doing something incorrect ?

It is working fine with DirectPipelineRunner.

```
2016-05-11T13:06:31.277Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2acbc): Checking required Cloud APIs are enabled.
2016-05-11T13:06:31.637Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2abc7): Expanding GroupByKey operations into optimizable parts.
2016-05-11T13:06:31.640Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a6b5): Lifting ValueCombiningMappingFns into MergeBucketsMappingFns
2016-05-11T13:06:31.646Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a77f): Annotating graph with Autotuner information.
2016-05-11T13:06:31.732Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a5c0): Fusing adjacent ParDo, Read, Write, and Flatten operations
2016-05-11T13:06:31.735Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a0ae): Fusing consumer ParDo(ParserEdition) into ReadEditions4GCS
2016-05-11T13:06:31.737Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2ab9c): Fusing consumer ParDo(GetRelatedArticles) into ParDo(FlattenArticles)
2016-05-11T13:06:31.739Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a68a): Fusing consumer GroupByKey/GroupByWindow into GroupByKey/Read
2016-05-11T13:06:31.741Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a178): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Ungroup into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow
2016-05-11T13:06:31.743Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2ac66): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Read
2016-05-11T13:06:31.745Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a754): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/Write2Gcs into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Ungroup
2016-05-11T13:06:31.747Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a242): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Write into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Reify
2016-05-11T13:06:31.750Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2ad30): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Reify into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/RandomKey
2016-05-11T13:06:31.752Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a81e): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/RandomKey into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Window.Into()
2016-05-11T13:06:31.754Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a30c): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Window.Into() into ParDo(Article2CSV)
2016-05-11T13:06:31.757Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2adfa): Fusing consumer ParDo(Article2CSV) into AnonymousParDo
2016-05-11T13:06:31.759Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a8e8): Fusing consumer GroupByKey/Write into GroupByKey/Reify
2016-05-11T13:06:31.761Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a3d6): Fusing consumer AnonymousParDo into GroupByKey/GroupByWindow
2016-05-11T13:06:31.763Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2aec4): Fusing consumer GroupByKey/Reify into ParDo(Article2KV)
2016-05-11T13:06:31.765Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a9b2): Fusing consumer ParDo(FlattenArticles) into ParDo(ParserEdition)
2016-05-11T13:06:31.768Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a4a0): Fusing consumer ParDo(Article2KV) into ParDo(GetRelatedArticles)
2016-05-11T13:06:31.815Z: Basic:  (eb15ba3070c2aa26): Worker configuration: n1-standard-1 in us-central1-f.
2016-05-11T13:06:32.154Z: Detail:  (eb15ba3070c2a931): Adding StepResource setup and teardown to workflow graph.
2016-05-11T13:06:32.262Z: Basic:  (120e40c18a94ee3a): Starting 3 workers...
2016-05-11T13:06:32.272Z: Basic:  S01: (b31e9392dace1359): Executing operation GroupByKey/Create
2016-05-11T13:06:32.504Z: Basic:  S02: (27044e90035e1dd6): Executing operation ReadEditions4GCS+ParDo(ParserEdition)+ParDo(FlattenArticles)+ParDo(GetRelatedArticles)+ParDo(Article2KV)+GroupByKey/Reify+GroupByKey/Write
2016-05-11T13:07:11.352Z: Detail:  (e26d7dfd74bb5700): Workers have started successfully.
2016-05-11T13:07:23.464Z: Error:   (91724060ab73dbcb): java.io.IOException: DATA_LOSS: Inconsistent number of records, parsed 108, expected 109 when dataflow-articlemetadatapipeline-g-05110606-31f5-harness-cmwd talking to tcp://localhost:12345
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.write(Native Method)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.writeChunk(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.close(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.close(ShuffleSink.java:272)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:254)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:180)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:161)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If i run the same code multiple times. i do get slightly different exception as well

```
2016-05-11T13:00:27.649Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3e7a): Checking required Cloud APIs are enabled.
2016-05-11T13:00:27.994Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3ed9): Expanding GroupByKey operations into optimizable parts.
2016-05-11T13:00:27.998Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc350f): Lifting ValueCombiningMappingFns into MergeBucketsMappingFns
2016-05-11T13:00:28.009Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc37b1): Annotating graph with Autotuner information.
2016-05-11T13:00:28.106Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc356e): Fusing adjacent ParDo, Read, Write, and Flatten operations
2016-05-11T13:00:28.110Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3ba4): Fusing consumer ParDo(ParserEdition) into ReadEditions4GCS
2016-05-11T13:00:28.112Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc31da): Fusing consumer ParDo(GetRelatedArticles) into ParDo(FlattenArticles)
2016-05-11T13:00:28.114Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3810): Fusing consumer GroupByKey/GroupByWindow into GroupByKey/Read
2016-05-11T13:00:28.117Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3e46): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Ungroup into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow
2016-05-11T13:00:28.120Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc347c): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Read
2016-05-11T13:00:28.124Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3ab2): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/Write2Gcs into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Ungroup
2016-05-11T13:00:28.127Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc30e8): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Write into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Reify
2016-05-11T13:00:28.129Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc371e): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/GroupByKey/Reify into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/RandomKey
2016-05-11T13:00:28.132Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3d54): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/RandomKey into Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Window.Into()
2016-05-11T13:00:28.135Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc338a): Fusing consumer Write2Gcs/FileBasedSink.ReshardForWrite/Window.Into() into ParDo(Article2CSV)
2016-05-11T13:00:28.137Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc39c0): Fusing consumer ParDo(Article2CSV) into AnonymousParDo
2016-05-11T13:00:28.139Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3ff6): Fusing consumer GroupByKey/Write into GroupByKey/Reify
2016-05-11T13:00:28.141Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc362c): Fusing consumer AnonymousParDo into GroupByKey/GroupByWindow
2016-05-11T13:00:28.144Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3c62): Fusing consumer GroupByKey/Reify into ParDo(Article2KV)
2016-05-11T13:00:28.146Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3298): Fusing consumer ParDo(FlattenArticles) into ParDo(ParserEdition)
2016-05-11T13:00:28.148Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc38ce): Fusing consumer ParDo(Article2KV) into ParDo(GetRelatedArticles)
2016-05-11T13:00:28.196Z: Basic:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3b3c): Worker configuration: n1-standard-1 in us-central1-f.
2016-05-11T13:00:28.459Z: Detail:  (7ad6fdbb36cc3b9b): Adding StepResource setup and teardown to workflow graph.
2016-05-11T13:00:28.639Z: Basic:  (cea9ab4bd124bf89): Starting 3 workers...
2016-05-11T13:00:28.658Z: Basic:  S01: (e5a53851aa035056): Executing operation GroupByKey/Create
2016-05-11T13:00:28.896Z: Basic:  S02: (5803a8f4cae47397): Executing operation ReadEditions4GCS+ParDo(ParserEdition)+ParDo(FlattenArticles)+ParDo(GetRelatedArticles)+ParDo(Article2KV)+GroupByKey/Reify+GroupByKey/Write
2016-05-11T13:01:12.228Z: Detail:  (5d4a90d7ea1437dd): Workers have started successfully.
2016-05-11T13:01:22.911Z: Error:   (f5a249985c78da4a): com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: unable to parse secondary key
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:213)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at uk.news.pipeline.api.ArticleMetaDataPipeline$Article2KV.processElement(ArticleMetaDataPipeline.java:147)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:213)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at uk.news.pipeline.api.ArticleMetaDataPipeline$GetRelatedArticles.lambda$processElement$0(ArticleMetaDataPipeline.java:71)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: unable to parse secondary key
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:176)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:38)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: unable to parse secondary key
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.write(Native Method)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.writeChunk(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.put(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:56)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:263)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.process(WriteOperation.java:90)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:38)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:213)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at uk.news.pipeline.api.ArticleMetaDataPipeline$Article2KV.processElement(ArticleMetaDataPipeline.java:147)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:213)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at uk.news.pipeline.api.ArticleMetaDataPipeline$GetRelatedArticles.lambda$processElement$0(ArticleMetaDataPipeline.java:71)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

2016-05-11T13:01:25.776Z: Error:   (e9a78cb2969ddea0): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DATA_LOSS: Inconsistent number of records, parsed 97, expected 98 when dataflow-articlemetadatapipeline-g-05110600-a71d-harness-p0a2 talking to tcp://localhost:12345
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:176)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:38)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DATA_LOSS: Inconsistent number of records, parsed 97, expected 98 when dataflow-articlemetadatapipeline-g-05110600-a71d-harness-p0a2 talking to tcp://localhost:12345
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.write(Native Method)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.writeChunk(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.put(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:56)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:263)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.process(WriteOperation.java:90)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.processElement(ReifyTimestampAndWindowsDoFn.java:38)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:213)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at uk.news.pipeline.api.ArticleMetaDataPipeline$Article2KV.processElement(ArticleMetaDataPipeline.java:147)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:213)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:487)
    at uk.news.pipeline.api.ArticleMetaDataPipeline$GetRelatedArticles.processElement(ArticleMetaDataPipeline.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:189)
```

....

Code :

```
  static class ParserEdition extends DoFn<String, Edition> {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            final String editionStr = c.element();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Edition.class);
            final Object editionObj = reader.readValue(editionStr);
            c.output((Edition)editionObj);
        }
    }

    static class FlattenArticles extends DoFn<Edition,Article>{

        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            final List<Article> articleList = c.element().getArticleList();
            for (Article a : articleList){
                c.output(a);
            }
        }
    }

    static class GetRelatedArticles extends DoFn<Article, Article>{

        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

            final Article tArticle = c.element();
            if(tArticle.getCategory().equals("article")){
                Article cloneArticle = (Article)SerializationUtils.clone(tArticle);
                cloneArticle.setImage(getRelatedImage(tArticle));
                c.output(cloneArticle);
                final List<Article> relateArticle = getRelateArticle(tArticle, 5);
                relateArticle.parallelStream().forEach(a -> c.output(a));
            }
        }

        public List<Article> getRelateArticle(Article art, int i){
            List<Article> list = new ArrayList<>();
            if(i <= 0 || art.getArticleList() == null){
                return null;
            }else {
                for(Article a : art.getArticleList()) {
                    if (a.getCategory().equals("article")) {
                        Article cloneArticle = (Article)SerializationUtils.clone(a);
                        cloneArticle.setImage(getRelatedImage(a));
                        list.add(cloneArticle);
                        final List<Article> relateArticle = getRelateArticle(a, i - 1);
                        if (relateArticle != null) {
                            list.addAll(relateArticle);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        public Image getRelatedImage(Article art){
            Image image = new Image();
            try{
                final Article article = art.getArticleList().parallelStream().filter(
                        a -> (a.getCategory().equals("image") && a.getIdentifier().equals(art.getLeadAssetId())))
                        .findFirst().get();
                if(article!=null){
                    image.setId(article.getIdentifier());
                    image.setImageUrl(URLEncoder.encode(article.getCrops().get(0).getImageId(), Charset.defaultCharset().name()));
                }
            }catch (Exception e){            }
            return image;
        }
    }

    static class Article2CSV extends DoFn<Article,String>{

        private String delimiter;

        Article2CSV(String delimiter){
            this.delimiter = delimiter;
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            final Article a = c.element();
            String str = a.getIdentifier()+delimiter+a.getTitle() +delimiter+getTeaserText(a) +
                    delimiter+a.getPublished() +delimiter+ a.getLeadAssetId() +
                    delimiter+ a.getImage().getImageUrl();
            c.output(str);
        }

        private String getTeaserText(Article a){
            String teaser = "";
            if(!a.getContent().isEmpty()){
                for(Content c : a.getContent()){
                    if(teaser.length() <= 100){
                        teaser =  teaser + c.getData().getText();
                    }
                }
            }
            return teaser;
        }
    }


    static class Article2KV extends DoFn<Article, KV<String, Article>> {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            final Article art = c.element();
            if(art!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(art.getIdentifier()))
                 c.output(KV.of(art.getIdentifier(),art));
        }
    }

........


      PipelineOptionsFactory.register(ArticleMetaDataOptions.class);
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(ArticleMetaDataOptions.class);

        final ArticleMetaDataOptions opts = (ArticleMetaDataOptions) options;
        if (!opts.isTestMode())
            options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);

        options.setDefaultWorkerLogLevel(DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions.Level.DEBUG);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        final PCollection<String> edition4GCS = p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadEditions4GCS")
                .from("gs://editions-newsuk/*"));

        // get articles from all the editions
        final PCollection<Article> articlePCollection = edition4GCS.apply(ParDo.of(new ParserEdition())).apply(ParDo.of(new FlattenArticles()));

        // get related articles
        final PCollection<Article> articles = articlePCollection.apply(ParDo.of(new GetRelatedArticles()));

        // convert into KV
        final PCollection<KV<String, Article>> articlesKV = articles.apply(ParDo.of(new Article2KV()));

        // Group by *** if this code below this commented. It then always works...
        final PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<Article>>> groupByCollection = articlesKV.apply(GroupByKey.<String, Article>create());


        // filter the duplicate/partial articles
        PCollection<Article> filterArticles = groupByCollection.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Article>>, Article>() {
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        String articleId = c.element().getKey();
                        Iterable<Article> arts = c.element().getValue();
                        boolean found = false;
                        Article article = null;
                        if(arts!=null){
                            for(Article at : arts){
                                article = at;
                                if(at!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(at.getImage().getImageUrl())){
                                    found = true;
                                    c.output(at);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(!found ){
                                c.output(article);
                            }
                        }
                    }}));


        // transform into file and persist to GCS
        filterArticles.apply(ParDo.of(new Article2CSV(opts.getDelimiter()))).apply(TextIO.Write.named("Write2Gcs").withoutSharding().to(opts.getOutputLocation()));
```

Comment: Could you share some more of the code for your `DoFn`s? For instance, `ParserEdition`, `FlattenArticles`, `GetRelatedArticles`, `Article2KV` or just a high-level summary of each of them? Could you share the job IDs associated with those jobs as well, so we can take a closer look?

Comment: Job Ids: 2016-05-11_05_39_43-14925035554635753922, 2016-05-11_05_46_24-2654288952822529571
2016-05-11_06_00_26-8122161173741086647,2016-05-11_06_06_30-17852890725098926978, 2016-05-11_06_20_15-7642311360028712413

Comment: @BenChambers, thanks. I have updated the code and jobsid in above comments..

Comment: Do you know if you're using any native code or libraries (via JNI) that may be corrupting memory?

Comment: I am not using any native code as far as per my understanding. does it is help if i give you import statements ?

Comment: Hrm, it looks like you're using `parallelStream`, which is likely calling the `output` methods in parallel. Outputting from a `DoFn` is not thread safe. Could you try either synchronizing the calls to output or using a non-parallel `forEach`?

Comment: thanks @BenChambers, It seems to be working. I have tried 3-4 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calls to `DoFn.Context#output` must be synchronized and complete before returning from the associated `startBundle`, `processElement` or `finishBundle` method.

In the code shared, it looks like you were using `someList.parallelStream().forEach(e -> c.output(e))` to output elements. The use of `parallelStream` violates the requirements.

Using a regular (non-parallel) `forEach` should prevent these problems.