# "java.io.IOException: INTERNAL" exceptions caused pipeline to fail

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a batch dataflow job which has several instances of `java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected` in the logs.

Digging deeper, I saw there were a few distinct exceptions:

- `java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Detected non-monotonic keys.`
- `java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Corruption: block checksum`
- `java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Corruption: bad entry in block`
- `java.io.IOException: DATA_LOSS: record checksum mismatch`

I believe this may just be a one-off bug, but I do not know the preferred place to report such issues so I'm posting here for visibility.

the job ID is `2017-01-26_13_26_59-15900546489513181319`

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if you would please provide a bit more information to help us resolve this issue.

Are your jars loading any native/JNI code?
Do you have a reliable way to reproduce this bug?

Comment: Hi Alex, we extended `FileBasedSink.FileBasedWriter` to write to a GZIPOutputStream. I don't have a reliable way to reproduce this bug, I have run this pipeline reading from different sources over 300 times and have only seen these internal errors in this job.

The only similarity between this failure and other failed jobs (< 10 overall) has been the presence of this exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Write rejected (writer id not found)`.

Comment: Also, I just re-ran this job with the same parameters and it succeeded this time.

Comment: I just had another job fail with similar exceptions: `INTERNAL: Corruption: block checksum mismatch`

I also saw this in the logs: `java.io.IOException: DATA_LOSS: unable to parse crc`
 
2017-01-30_14_45_44-3398384471818798752

Comment: Has it occurred recently? I think that this was a transient issue with the service, please let me know if it occurs again. Hopefully its working now for you.

Comment: Hi Alex, things are working fine now. I figured this was a transient failure, I just posted this for anyone seeing this exception in the future. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the result of a bad machine handling shuffle data, and indicates an unrecoverable failure for that specific run of the job.  If the issue persists over multiple runs, please see [Google dataflow, DATA_LOSS Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163200/google-dataflow-data-loss-exception) for potential threading issues.